# AngularJS 1.x.x. List all active controllers into browser's console

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to list all active controller names into console? Need this for external E2E testing, to check if controller has loaded without waiting for DOM to fully render.

Comment: log a message inside your controller function `Console.log("MyController loaded!")`

Comment: You need to explain your issue further, there is likely XY problem. What are *active controller names*? They are `ng-controller` controllers or any controllers, including components and routes?

Comment: @estus those are pretty much any controllers, which are created with `.controller()` method. Adding a `console.log` to each of'em is not so good, because production version would need to strip all unneeded console.logs somehow and also because of big size of an application.

Comment: @estus btw, by the "active controllers" I also mean only "controllers which are currently initialized and loaded"

Comment: You need to decorate `$controller` for that. This is information that doesn't make sense to me in the context of e2e testing. That's why I reasonably assume that it is XY problem that can be solved in more conventional way. Are you aware that a lot of controllers don't have names? They are just anonymous functions.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, and maybe you're right here. I'll try to discuss this with people who will be actually doing this kind of testing.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the comment you can log a message inside your controller to monitor when it is used.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('MyController', function(){
    Console.log("MyController loaded !")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it's not a good idea, as those comments are not good for production. Also size of an application doesn't allow me to add this `console.log` for each of existing controllers.